# Find the number of natural number solutions of $a+2b+c=100$

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, combinations

> Find the number of natural number solutions of $a+2b+c=100$

I remember something like stars and bars if the equation I change to $a+b_{1}+b_{2}+c=100$

then i get $\dbinom{99}{3}$ ways.

If the equation is like $a_{1}+a_{2}+a_{3}+a_{4}=m$ I can use $\dbinom{m-1}{3}$ ways

how ever I am not familier with variation in the problem.

I look for a short and simple way.

I have studied maths upto $12$th grade. thanks.

Comment: It's almost the same problem. You are only adding the restriction that one of the summands must be even, so that will reduce the number of possibilities. Consider the _unrestricted_ version (that is, where we are simply counting solutions in $\mathbb{N}$ to $a+b+c = 100$). Ask yourself this: out of all the solutions, how many have $b$ odd, and how many have $b$ even?

Comment: Half are even and half are odd.

Comment: Try some examples for values smaller than $100$ (something close to $10$, say).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I will assume that by the natural numbers that you mean the positive integers (as opposed to the nonnegative integers).

Observe that $a + c = 100 - 2b$ is an even number.  Thus, $a$ and $c$ must have the same parity.

**Case 1:**  The numbers $a$ and $c$ are both even.  Let $a = 2u$; let $c = 2v$.  Then $u, v \in \mathbb{N}$.  Moreover,
\begin{align*}
a + 2b + c & = 100\\
2u + 2b + 2v & = 100\\
u + b + v & = 50 \tag{1}
\end{align*}
which is an equation in positive integers. The number of solutions of equation 1 is the number of ways we can place two addition signs in the $49$ spaces between consecutive ones in a row of $50$ ones, which is $\binom{49}{2}$.

**Case 2:**  The numbers $a$ and $c$ are both odd.  Let $a = 2s - 1$; let $b = 2t - 1$.  Then $s, t \in \mathbb{N}$.  Moreover,
\begin{align*}
a + 2b + c & = 100\\
2s - 1 + 2b + 2t - 1 & = 100\\
2s + 2b + 2t & = 102\\
s + b + t & = 51 \tag{2}
\end{align*}
which is an equation in positive integers.  The number of solutions of equation 2 is the number of ways two addition signs can be placed in the $50$ spaces that appear between consecutive ones in a row of $51$ ones, which is $\binom{50}{2}$.

Thus, the number of solutions of the equation $a + 2b + c = 100$ in the positive integers is 
$$\binom{49}{2} + \binom{50}{2} = 1176 + 1225 = 2401$$

Answer (score 10):

I assume that $a,b,c\ge 1$.

You can use the method you write for 
$$a+c=100-2b$$
where $b=1,2,\cdots,49$.

Then, the answer is
$$\sum_{b=1}^{49}\binom{99-2b}{1}=99\times 49-2\cdot\frac{49\cdot 50}{2}=49(99-50)=49^2=\color{red}{2401}.$$